# Nokogiri check XML root/file validity

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Is there a simple method/way to check if a `Nokogiri XML` file has a proper root, like `xml.valid?` A way to check if the XML file contains specific content is very welcome as well.

I'm thinking of something like `xml.valid?` or `xml.has_valid_root?`. Thanks!

Comment: try `valid?` or `validate`

Comment: `valid?` gives me undefined method `valid?` for #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x007fd9ed7c8098>. I'll try validate. Thanks.

Comment: look [this](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet#xsd-validation)

Comment: @Monk_Code That's a method on a `Schema` (XSD) object, not an XML object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you going to determine what is a proper root?

```
<foo></foo>
```

has a proper root:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '<foo></foo>'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.root # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd3a9471b7c name="foo">
```

Nokogiri has no way of determining that something else should have been the root. *You* might be able to test if you have foreknowledge of what the root node's name should be:

```
doc_root_ok = (doc.root.name == 'foo')
doc_root_ok # => true
```

You *can* see if the document parsed was well-formed (not needing any fixup), by looking at `errors`:

```
doc.errors # => []
```

If Nokogiri had to modify the document just to parse it, [`errors`](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/ensuring_well_formed_markup.html) will return a list of changes that were made prior to parsing:

```
xml = '<foo><bar><bar></foo>'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: bar line 1 and foo>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag bar line 1>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag foo line 1>]
```

Comment: Technically speaking, `doc.errors` will tell you if the document is well-formed, but it won't tell you if it is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the code examples, I they're the solution to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A common and useful pattern is

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml) do |config|
  config.strict
end
```

This will throw a wobbly if the document is not well formed. I like to do this in order to *prevent* Nokogiri from being too kind to my XML.

Comment: Would I then catch it with `rescue wobbly`?